# What version of the same DLL does VS choose if there are more than one in the GAC?

Tags: visual-studio, gac, system.data.sqlite

I've been developing for a while in a project involving SQLITE and .NET.
Recently, SQLITE have released a new version. I decided to install it to the GAC(the same as I did with the previous installation).
Now, I can see two dlls in the GAC. Does VS automatically pick to use the latest one?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dependent on [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if the full path of the DLL is not used within the application. The default order (`SafeDllSearchMode` disabled):

> - The directory from which the application loaded.
> - The current directory.
> - The system directory. Use the `GetSystemDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> - The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> - The Windows directory. Use the `GetWindowsDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> - The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by
>     the **App Paths** registry key. The **App Paths** key is not used when
>     computing the DLL search path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike.

I read the contents of your link, however something is unclear to me.

It seems that in my case the DLL is found by searching the Windows dir(in my case Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.SQLite)

However, there are two versions in there. I cannot determine by reading your link whether it is used the first or the second one.

Or maybe there is some way to find out in runtime which dll is used?

Comment: OK, I think I found out a way to check which version is used.
If you watch the Output window in VS you will see all the DLLs loaded. In this case is loaded the first one.


Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: A search for a DLL is performed by name. How can there be two versions in the same directory?

Comment: Maybe my wording wasn't that clear, but there are two directories for each version.